# Partition a graph around two vertices

Tags: clustering, graph-theory

Given an undirected weighted graph G and two distinct vertices (v1, v2) in the graph, I want to create two partitions V1 and V2, such that v1 is a member of V1, v2 is a member of V2, and sums of weights of the edges in each V1 and V2 are minimum. For example -

Given the graph with V= {a, b, c, d}, and weights as

(a, b) -> 8,

(a, c) -> 2,

(a, d) -> 3,

(b, c) -> 3,

(b, d) -> 1, and

(c, d) -> 7

and the two nodes, a and d, the partition will be {a, c}, and {d, b}

I would appreciate if one can point me to an algorithm that can achieve the above.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not seem to belong to CV -- maybe math?

Comment: This is hilarious! Just moved this question from StackOverflow.  Let me now try Math!

Comment: BTW,  this is a clustering problem- I believe it belongs here.  Let me know, if I am not correct.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. SO is for specific programming questions that are interesting to more than one person. Your question seems to be about the tagged topic "graph-theory", which has application in statistics, but is not its topic. And I don't see a general question. Please make it more clear, if your question is about finding a solution for a specific problem; please indicate if you already know the domain of the problem or not. In short: make your question clearer and more to the point. As far as I can see, there is no statistics involved the answer -- so it doesn't seem fitting here.

Comment: I do think this fits to CV reasonably well. This is a variation of mincut (with the constraints that v1 and v2 must be in the two partitions, and apparently a max cut?) which usually relates to an eigenvalue of some appropriately chosen graph laplacian.